# Integration Testing Entity Framework CRD operations

Tags: entity-framework, integration-testing, crud

I'm struggling with Integration Tests when using Entity Framework.

I seed my database with Test data in my Test project, but I am wondering how you manange to test the Create, Update and Delete operations.

Basicly I have my Test data which e.g. contains 5 customer entries... I can now write some unit tests to get the data based on these 5 entries. (e.g. get all will return a collection containing 5 items).

But what if I have a test which deletes 1 customer, this means the GetAll test will expect 5 customers, but only return 4 (if this test is executed after the delete test) and fails.

How do you work around this issue? Do you give a certain order to your tests or reseed the database before every test (but this sounds so bad?)...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An effective way to do this is to use [Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). This basically wraps all sql calls and rolls back changes if the scope is disposed without calling the Complete method. The basic test will look like this.

```
public class TransactionalTestsBase
{
    private TransactionScope _scope;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _scope = new TransactionScope();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        _scope.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CrudAction()
    {
        var repo = new YourRepo();
        var client = ; // Make client
        repo.DeleteClient(client);
        Assert.AreEqual(4,repo.GetClients().Count());
    }
}
```

Ideally you would inherit from this base test class not write your tests in it.

There is some new heat in beta still that I think will help with this greatly in the future. Have a look at [Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com/)

Comment: SO using this, CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE operations will not affect the actual database ?

Comment: No. Not at all. It is wrapped in a transaction scope. This means that all changes are only committed when you call scope.Complete(). Since we are never committing the scope and dispose it after each test nothing is written to the db.

Comment: " Since we are never committing the scope and dispose it after each test nothing is written to the db. " Then it is not an integration test.